# Node change global package version

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I have two pc's that don't have matching global package versions. I want to downgrade the one pc because that is the one that is working. Here the pc has a global typescript 2.9.2.

[image]

**How do I change this to typescript 2.9.1?** I tried all of these but it doesn't change anything. When I run `ng v` I still see typescript 2.9.2.

```
npm install -g typescript@2.9.1

npm install -g typescript@2.9.1 -- save

npm uninstall -g typescript
npm install -g typescript@2.9.1
```

- Going from 2.9.2 to 2.9.1 is just an example, so don't ask why I want
  to do this :)
- I run `ng v` on the C: location, so I am sure it is the global versions, not something local to a project

Comment: Did you try to use *--save-exact* option?